# How to display upload multi files's count in django admin?

Tags: django

I can upload multi files ，but how to display multi files count at list_display...

models.py

```
class PaperManager(models.Model):
    ...

class PaperFile(models.Model):
  image = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/')
  project = models.ForeignKey(PaperManager)
```

admin.py

```
class PaperFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        pass

class ProjectFileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PaperFile
    max_num=10
    extra=0
admin.site.register(PaperFile, PaperFileAdmin)

class PaperAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    inlines = [ProjectFileInline, ]
    list_display = ('id', ...)
    ...
admin.site.register(PaperManager,PaperAdmin)
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: OK，I got it，used get_queryset。